# Debugging Redis OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'

Tags: ruby, redis

I'm using a Redis-labs free instance of Redis and I keep getting an OOM error that says `OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'`. Below is tihe output of `info memory` but it's pretty sparse in detail. How can I debug this?

```
> info memory
# Memory
used_memory:12819464
used_memory_human:12.22M
used_memory_rss:12819464
used_memory_peak:72779296
used_memory_peak_human:69.40M
used_memory_lua:37888
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
```

Comment: There can be several reasons for that and not enough data. Your Redis vendor might have more information on it, I suggest opening a support ticket with them.

Comment: You could install redis locally and run the same commands and compare output. You should also be able to obtain memory usage locally and compare that with any published limitations of your hosted redis.